# In my android studio, the phone are not being recognized, only loading is coming, Dies anyone know about it?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been trying to connect my phone through USB and android studio is not identifying it. Earlier I have run programs on my mobile but suddenly it started to show only loading. I have tried to clear cache in settings but when I try to find ADB in device manager, I could not find it. I don't know what to do and I am really stuck, help me out, please.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and what helped me was

1. Go to developer options
2. Find Select USB configurations and click it
3. Choose MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)

If that dosent work you can try opening cmd in your platform-tools folder inside your sdk folder and from there try restarting the adb server

Answer (score 0):

Go to  mobile setting and go to about phone or like that and tap build number 5 times and your devoloper settings enabled .
First turn on usb debugging in phone settings.
Enable App installing Via Usb .
connect usb cable and
disconnect cable again it will be working.